# Criteria Query with Joined Inheritance

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, spring-data-jpa, criteria

I have a join chain:

The first one:

```
@Entity
public class Anuncio implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Produto produto;
```

The second one:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Produto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
```

And  the third one:

```
@Entity
public class Bovino extends Produto implements Serializable  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

I made a relationship between `Anuncio` and `Produto`, and extends `Produto` to a lot of classes, let's take the `Bovino` for a sample.

I'm trying to use CriteriaBuilder to make some queries, but idk how to chain the entities. I need to search properties across the three entities, but I can't find a solution by myself.  Due to be an child class, `Bovino` doesn't have an Id field, I let the work to JPA Inheritance. I'm using `Predicates` to add some conditions to criteriaBuilder, like this:

```
public List<Anuncio> getFilteredBuilder(Integer qualidadeGado, Integer racaGado, Integer idadeStart, Integer idadeEnd){
        
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Anuncio> cq = cb.createQuery(Anuncio.class);
        Root<Anuncio> rootAn = cq.from(Anuncio.class);
        
        List<Predicate> preds  = new ArrayList<>();
        if (qualidadeGado != null) {
            preds.add(cb.equal(rootAn.get("qualidade"), qualidadeGado));
        }
        if (racaGado != null) {
            preds.add(cb.equal(rootAn.get("raca"), racaGado));
        }
        if (idadeStart != null ) {
            preds.add(cb.ge(rootAn.get("idadeOuMedia"), idadeStart));
        }
        if (idadeEnd != null) {
            preds.add(cb.le(rootAn.get("idadeOuMedia"), idadeEnd));
        }
        cq.where(preds.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        
        return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }
```

How can I code a query searching properties across the three entities with criteria queries?